# How to convert hashed password to normal text using php

Tags: php, hash

I have hashed password in my database. actually I have to convert this password to normal text.

Below is my password,

'6fad15b73f04cba8fd65da0d621fa42eff61001b'.

I have tried like below but its not working,

```
$enc = "6fad15b73f04cba8fd65da0d621fa42eff61001b";
$dec = base64_decode ($enc);
echo $dec;die;
```

Comment: How you are creating this password ? You can't decode it but you can verify with other string.

Comment: Your password is not base64 encoded. So it can not be decoded with `base64_decode` function.

Comment: A hashing algorithm is an one-way algorithm and can not be converted back. That you can not convert it back is a feature of hashing and intended for passwords.

Comment: And the inventor of `hash` sleeps restfully in their grave.

Comment: You should never need (or be able to) revert a password hash. If you need to, then you should rethink your design and what you're doing. If you _do_ manage to revert it, it means that you're using a weak hashing algorithm and you should, again, rethink your design. When storing and verifying passwords, always use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base64 **encoding** is something completely different than **hashing**.

You can read about base64 here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

And about hashing here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function

Or search the infromation by yourself (also recommend video about hashing from computherphile channel on youtube).

Long story short: there is no option to convert hashed text back to plain text. Thats the reason why we use that method to store password - only the author of a password can know the real value - nobody else (developers and someone who can stole passwords). The popular method used to break hashed password is called "brute force attack" and is based on comparing already known hashed values of popular passwords to existing ones in database.

Way of logging to application is most commonly based on hashing the password a user typed in during logging in and comparing if its value equals the value already existing in database. The plain value of password should not be stored in any kind of long term memory in application.

Its practically impossible for you to convert hashed password back.

Also I recommend to read about differences between **encoding** and **encryption** and **hashing**. Here is concise article about that: http://www.differencebetween.info/difference-between-encryption-encoding-and-hashing

Answer (score 0):

A hash cryptographic function is a one way function which means that you can convert your password to a hash, but you can not easily convert your hash to a password.

Comment: Then what is the solution

Comment: You can just verify to check password

Comment: There is no solution, what you're asking (converting a hash to it's original text) is impossible, or very difficult. Could you elaborate on what you are trying to do in the grander scheme? Are you trying to check if someone's password is correct against a hashed version in your database?

Comment: i need to use the hashed value to make an api call... but its hashed so the key isn't correct when i make a call. therefore throwing an error, invalid key